# Why can't i map a range of number to another range of number in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, styles, opacity

I'm making this blurry effect so that my percentage will go blurrier as it gets to 100%. However, it doesn't work...the console says "Cannot access '*scale' before initialization
at blurring* " which is in line 16 of my script.js.
Anybody knows what is wrong please help me! Thank you so much!

This is my code:

```js
const loadText = document.querySelector('.loading-text')
const bg = document.querySelector('.bg')
let load = 0
let int = setInterval(blurring, 30)

function blurring() {
  load++

  if (load > 99) {
    clearInterval(int)
  }

  loadText.innerText = `${load}%`
  loadText.style.opacity = scale(load, 0, 100, 1, 0)

  const scale = (num, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max) => {
    return ((num - in_min) * (out_max - out_min)) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.bg {
  background: url('z.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  left: -30px;
  width: calc(100vw + 60px);
  height: calc(100vw + 60px);
  z-index: -1;
  filter: blur(0px)
}

.loading-text {
  padding: 50% 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Blurry Loading</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section class="bg">
    <div class="loading-text">
      0%
    </div>
  </section>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to call "scale" before you've initialized the function. Move

```
const scale = (num, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max) => {
        return ((num - in_min) * (out_max - out_min)) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min
    }
```

above

```
loadText.style.opacity = scale(load, 0, 100, 1, 0)
```

Comment: Or use `function` instead of `const`, since it's automatically hoisted.

Comment: Yep, they could also just move it out of the blurring function.

Comment: yah i did it and it worked but when i add the code to load the background image from blur(30) to blur(0) just like this: " loadText.innerText = ${load}% loadText.style.opacity = scale(load, 0, 100, 1, 0) bg.style.filter = blur(${scale(load, 0, 100, 30, 0)}px)" the image works but the loading text cannot be seen, i mean i can't see the loading text stan dout as bigger z-index compare to "z-index: -1" of ".bg". Do you guys know why?

Comment: Sorry if i don't expain it too well but it'd be kind of you guys to help!